# Resize Photos by 50% script erases key geotag metadata

Tags: resize, photo

I am working on a python script that will later be used as a tool in ArcGIS Pro that will take the photos from a drone, resize them by 50%, then run a geotag to point process. Right now, the script is set to copy all the photos into a new folder called "images_resized" as a way to indicate that these are the photos to be used and uploaded while the raw unchaged photos stay in the root folder. The issue I am running into is that when I run the resize part of the script, I end up losing the key location data I need for the script to run properly.

```
import os
import arcpy
from sys import argv
from datetime import date
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image
import shutil
source_folder_path = r"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\UASPhotos"
# Specify the destination folder path
destination_folder_path = r"{}\images_resized".format(source_folder_path)
# Create the destination folder if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(destination_folder_path):
    os.makedirs(destination_folder_path)
# Get a list of all files in the source folder
file_list = os.listdir(source_folder_path)
# Loop through each file in the source folder
for file_name in file_list:
    # Create the source and destination paths
    source_path = os.path.join(source_folder_path, file_name)
    destination_path = os.path.join(destination_folder_path, file_name)

    # Check if the file is an image (you can add more file extensions if needed)
    if file_name.lower().endswith((".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".bmp", ".gif")):
        # Copy the file to the destination folder
        shutil.copyfile(source_path, destination_path)

        # Open the image file from the destination folder
        with Image.open(destination_path) as image:
            # Calculate the new width and height
            new_width = int(image.width * 0.5)
            new_height = int(image.height * 0.5)

            # Resize the image
            resized_image = image.resize((new_width, new_height))

            # Copy the original image's metadata to the resized image
            resized_image.info = image.info

            # Save the resized image, overwriting the original file
            resized_image.save(destination_path)
```

I know it's during the resize because I tried just the copy and the photos still had the info, but as soon as I run the resizer the data is gone. Any ideas on how to preserve the essental metadata or any work around?

Edit:
I also found and tried out some EXIF scripts basically running the code below but still nothing

```
   for file_name in files:
    # Get the full path of the source file
    source_file = os.path.join(source_folder, file_name)

    # Check if the file is an image
    if not os.path.isfile(source_file) or not file_name.lower().endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png')):
        continue

    # Open the image using PIL
    image = Image.open(source_file)

    # Resize the image
    width, height = image.size
    new_width = int(width * resize_percentage)
    new_height = int(height * resize_percentage)
    resized_image = image.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    # Preserve the geotag information
    exif_data = image.info.get("exif")
    resized_image.info["exif"] = exif_data


    # Save the resized image to the destination folder
    destination_file = os.path.join(destination_folder, file_name)
    resized_image.save(destination_file)

    # Close the image
    image.close()
    resized_image.close()
```